# Search bar - punctuation and latex

Tags: support, search

I want to search for posts with quantum states $| i \rangle$. Is there any way to search for latex expressions. Is there any way to include puntuation in searches.

I know google ignores puncuation, but for scientific content, these features are important.

Comment: Note that some people write such a state `$|i>$`, some use `$|i\rangle$`, some use `$\left|i\right>$`, and occasionally some vandal will use `$\newcommand\ket[1]{\left|{#1}\right>} \ket i$`.

Comment: So is there a way to seach for the code, and is the a way to search for the result, and related results?

Comment: That I don't know. A site search for `|i\rangle` on the main site brings plenty of questions with states in them, but not limited to states labeled $i$. Adding quotes to the search term doesn't appear to remove search results with stuff between the `i` and the `\rangle`. Hopefully someone who is a heavier search user than I am will answer.

Comment: FYI: A [Math SE user](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/111262/wei-zhong) had developed [Approach0](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/announcing-a-third-party-search-engine-for-math-stackexchange) for these type of advanced searches involving MathJax. As of now works it only for Math SE and is still under development. But hopefully, it can be extended to include other SE sites as well, in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The [in-built SE search](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search) is not sufficient for this.

> [@rob](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10971/search-bar-punctuation-and-latex#comment42203_10971): A site search for `|i\rangle` on the main site brings plenty of
>   questions with states in them, but not limited to states labeled `i`.
>   Adding quotes to the search term doesn't appear to remove search
>   results with stuff between the `i` and the `\rangle`.

Indeed, that's what I observed too. However, for the time being you can use [this SE Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/revision/961720/1192754/exact-string-search) to search for exact strings like `$|i>$`, `$|i\rangle$`, `$\left|i\right>$` and `$\newcommand\ket[1]{\left|{#1}\right>} \ket i$`.

```
select top 100
    Id as [Post Link]
from
    Posts
where
    Body like '%<enter-specific-string-here>%'
```

In case you're interested, [here's](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) a quick tutorial for the Data Explorer.

By the way, I think you're asking this question because of: [Notational conventions of the Bloch sphere](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5185/notational-conventions-of-the-bloch-sphere). Remember that most sources using $|i\rangle$ to *label* quantum states rather than using it to denote $|0\rangle + i|1\rangle$. I'm afraid the search results won't be too useful for you unless you manage to be lucky.